take product information and insert it into e2pdf
I am compiling a pdf with wordpress more precisely with plug-in e2pdf. I have a form inside the page of every single product (for the request of information) until I take the written information in the form is all ok. I would like to take other information on the page (which are not present in the form)
I would like to take other information on the page (which are not present in the form)
